# how to debug `Null reference exception occured` in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
string search = textBoxNachname.Text;
var Liste = _db.T_Subscribers
                .Where(x => x.firstname.StartsWith(search))
                .Except(_selectedcourse.T_Coursedetail.Select(b => b.T_Subscribers))
                .Where(M => M.T_Tln_Student == null || M.T_Tln_Stud.Status.T_Status.T_Statusart == _studentEx).ToList();
```

I have written the above piece of code to extract a list whose name starts with the Search element in textbox...then I need to exclude the names who have already enrolled for the course, then if they are not the students of the Institution `(M => M.T_Tln_Student == null)` and ex-students include in the list..

But I am getting Null reference exception occurred...

Comment: Have you tried sticking a breakpoint in the expressions to see what is null? Any answer to this could only make guesses...

Comment: Split the linq statements out and see which one is throwing the exception

Comment: you can't add breakpoints inside a linq query. The error you get means that 1 of your parameters is null.

Comment: @patxy Is that a linq to sql limitation? I do it with linq to objects frequently.

Comment: Easiest thing to do - put a breakpoint at the line `string search....`. When you hit that breakpoint, hover the mouse over various things in the LINQ query such as `x`, `x.firstname`, `_selectedcourse` etc. You need to know exactly what is set to `NULL.`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth : in fact, when he will put a breakpoint, the whole query will be highlighted

Comment: @patxy Ah, I guess you mean by clicking in the side-bar, which you are correct will highlight the entire row. I am not referring to this. Have you tried right clicking the expression content itself and doing "Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint"? I might have just made your life a little easier... I wish people would check the facts before up-voting incorrect things.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thx, it appears i didn't know about that. (and I just tryed it in linq to sql)

Comment: @patxy I cannot speak for Linq to SQL as I never use it, I only use Linq to Objects, hence my initial question for clarification. Personally I would break the expressions out into method groups that can be debugged a little more clearly.

Comment: Yeah I did and it is the last 2 expressions(Except and where ) which are null...

Comment: By the way.. this is a good example of why method chains is not necessarily a good practice and why the principal of shorter code = better code is only correct as long as it's debug-able on the fly :/

Comment: @JensKloster Null reference ones are notorious in being very localised and not demonstrating qualities such as attempts to address or understand the problem. Plus "Pls help ... Thx in advance" kind of markers tend to feature frequently on oft-downvoted / poor quality questions. I have rescinded my downvote, but it's not worth an up-vote IMO. I'm not saying any of these are *valid* reasons for downvoting, just my observations on what tends to happen. I actually think a perfect answer for these types of questions is a community wiki on debugging basics - the genesis of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can debug this:

```
var Liste1 = _db.T_Subscribers.Where(x => x.firstname.StartsWith(search));
var Liste2 = Liste1.Except(
               _selectedcourse.T_Coursedetail.Select(b => b.T_Subscribers));
var Liste3 = Liste2.Where(M =>
                M.T_Tln_Student == null ||
                M.T_Tln_Stud.Status.T_Status.T_Statusart == _studentEx);
var Liste = Liste3.ToList();
```

The focus is to use this technique to split things.

Answer (score 0):

look at this line:

```
.Where(M => M.T_Tln_Student == null || 
            M.T_Tln_Stud             // might be null
                        .Status      // might be null
                        .T_Status    // might be null
                        .T_Statusart // might be null
                           == _studentEx)
```

I would suggest that you start your search for the NullReferenceException here

```
.Where(M => M.T_Tln_Student == null || 
            M.T_Tln_Stud == null ||
            M.T_Tln_Stud.Status == null||
            M.T_Tln_Stud.Status.T_Status == null ||
            M.T_Tln_Stud.Status.T_Status.T_Statusart == null ||
            M.T_Tln_Stud.Status.T_Status.T_Statusart == _studentEx)
```